# Odata request, query from SQL database, filter on field with JSON string format

Tags: json, sql-server, filter, odata, httprequest

I'm running HTTP request against application which is querying SQL database (assumption), and I want to filter on a field which stores JSON format string. I want to filter on properties within the JSON

We have data in table QueueItems like these (first 3 columns)

```
Id      Priority    QueueDefinitionId
48835   1           387
48840   1           387
```

So if I run request with endpoint
`"odata/QueueItems?$filter=QueueDefinitionId eq 387"` it returns a result, JSON format all columns

We have a column like this

```
SpecificData
{"DynamicProperties":{"itemID":"Elantris"}}
{"DynamicProperties":{"itemID":"Elantris"}}
```

Now I want to run filter on `SpecificData/DynamicProperties/itemID eq 'Elantris'`

I'm aware of possibility to treat it as string, and use function contains. I would prefer more reliable method.

So far I was unable to find the solution to this

Any help appreciated

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution for the above?